# Exchange subplots in figure

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, figure, subplot

I create a figure containing 4 subplots like:

```
y = [2 2 3; 2 5 6; 2 8 9; 2 11 12];
fig = figure
for i = 1 : 4
    h(i) = subplot(1,4,i)
    bar(y)
end
```

Now I would like to exchange the order of the subplots. For example the first subplot should go in the last column (4th) and the 2nd subplot should exchange with the 3rd.

Is it doable without generating again the figure?

Answer (score 5):

Perhaps you could change their `'position'` of the axes `h`. For instance:

```
% get position
pos = get(h,'position');
% change position, 1st <-> 4th, 2nd <->3rd.
set(h(1),'position',pos{4});
set(h(4),'position',pos{1});
set(h(2),'position',pos{3});
set(h(3),'position',pos{2});
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a possibility which kind of regenerates the figure. You can go to the plot tools, right click the figure and select "Show code". This will open a new file with a function that recreates the figure. There you can change your subplot-position and call the function in order to obtain the figure with switched subplots.

While this recreates the figure, you do not have to re-evaluate the function or script that originally created the figure.

PS: I'm not sure how new this feature is.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to swapping the `Position` property of the `axes` objects, you could also swap the `Parent` property of the `bar` objects. This has the advantage of leaving your `axes` positioning intact.

A simple example:

```
function testcode

y1 = [2 2 3; 2 5 6; 2 8 9; 2 11 12];
y2 = -y1;

h(1) = subplot(1, 2, 1);
b(1,:) = bar(y1);
h(2) = subplot(1, 2, 2);
b(2,:) = bar(y2);

swapbar(h, b, [1,2]);
end

function swapbar(axesobjects, barobjects, axesswap)
    set(barobjects(axesswap(1), :), 'Parent', axesobjects(axesswap(2)));
    set(barobjects(axesswap(2), :), 'Parent', axesobjects(axesswap(1)));
end
```

Here I've created a small helper function `swapbar` to swap two axes. This isn't at all a robust implementation but it works well to illustrate the concept.

Old:

[image: old]

New:

[image: yay]